# What is the difference between chart.options.yAxis and chart.yAxis in highcharts (highStock)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In a highchart (highstock) object, I want to understand the difference between chart.options.yAxis and chart.yAxis.

When I add a y-axis to the chart I see an object getting added to both the places. It also removes from both the places if I remove an axis. I see a discrepancy when using navigator, as chart.yAxis contains an object for navigator whereas chart.options.yAxis does not contain an object for navigator.

My doubt is how should I update yAaxis dynamically? 
Here is a scenario:
My chart loads with 2 y-Axis. So the chart.YAxis array contains the 2 y-Axis I loaded the chart with plus an object for the navigator (total 3). Now, when I add another axis dynamically (using chart.addAxis() )it becomes the 4th index in chart.yAxis and the 3rd index in chart.options.yAxis. Which index should I be using if I want to update this new axis dynamically using chart.yAxis[].update().

Note that now if I update the axis using the 4th index (chart.yAxis[3].update({})) it adds another item in the chart.options.yAxis array, hence now chart.options.yAxis contains 2 items for the same axis.

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420950/highcharts-highstock-highcharts-does-not-remove-yaxis-as-expected) question is connected to the one above? As I said there, instead of playing around indexes I would use `ID` and later get corresponding axis using `chart.get(ID)`. However, could you setup demo with duplicated yAxis in `chart.options`?

Comment: You can add a id for each yAxis and then use [get()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get) function to refer to particular axis.